# Can I use Bootstrap classes in my JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there is a possibility to use bootstrap classes in JavaScript, for example (has-warning):

```
function submitName() {

    var inputName = document.querySelector('#inputName'),
    sName = inputName.value;

    if (sName == '') {
        inputName.classList.add("has-warning");
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, yes, they are for that only...

Answer (score 1):

Yup Keneth. You can freely to use the bootstrap classes in your own external js file or add js logics between script tag after footer before script tag.

***But I will suggest you make your own id or classes. That's is a bad practice to using bootstrap classes for your external logic.***

Comment: great! thanks Subhojit... I was asking about it because it wasn't working. Now it is. The only thing is that I dont know if apply it correctly

Answer (score 0):

yes you can , just be sure that the bootstrap css file is imported correctly .